# How to gsub slash "/" with back slash and slash "\/" in ruby

Tags: ruby, gsub

I try to modify `"/foo/bar/dir"` to `"\/foo\/bar\/dir"` by ruby gsub command.

I test it in irb the result is

```
x = "/foo/bar/dir"

x.gsub("/","\/")

=> "/foo/bar/dir"

x.gsub("/","\\/")

=> "\\/foo\\/bar\\/dir"
```

**Is it possible to replace "/" with "/" by gsub ?**

---

Source of problems:

I try to execute "string in command line" and "real_path" is my variable

```
real_path = "/home/me/www/idata"

path = real_path.gsub("/","\\/")

=> \\/home\\/me\\/www\\/idata 

# But what I expect is \/home\/me\/www\/idata

run "sed 's/SHARE_PATH/#{path}/g' #{path}/config/sphinx.yml > #{path}/config/sphinx.tmp.yml"
```

result from "run" command is

```
"sh -c 'sed '\''s/SHARE_PATH/\\/home\\/me\\/www\\/idata\\/shared/g .... "
```

I need is only one back slash like

```
"sh -c 'sed '\''s/SHARE_PATH/\/home\/me\/www\/idata\/shared/g .... "
```

"run" is command from Capistrano

**my solution is**

use single quote instead of double quote like this

```
path = real_path.gsub("/",'\/')
```

Comment: How does the `real_path` look like? I mean what is the output of `puts real_path`? As I said, You are asking about "/" to "\/" modification but You have `gsub("\/", "\\/")`

Comment: gsub("/","\\/") and gsub("\/","\\/") will return the same result. It will add one "\\" infront of "/"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Yes

```
irb(main):028:0> (t = x.gsub("/", "\\/")) && nil
=> nil
irb(main):029:0> t
=> "\\/foo\\/bar\\/dir"
irb(main):030:0> puts t
\/foo\/bar\/dir
=> nil
```

Your first example actually did what you wanted, but the `.inspect` method that irb is using is escaping backslashes, so it looked like there were extras. If you had used `puts` you would have seen the real result.

Answer (score 8):

You have written:

```
x = "/foo/bar/dir"
x.gsub("/","\\/")
=> "\\/foo\\/bar\\/dir"
```

so You did what You had asked before. `x.gsub("/","\\/")` in fact evaluates to `"\/foo\/bar\/dir"` but irb prints return value of `inspect` method instead of `to_s`.

**Edit:** Did You mean

```
real_path.gsub("/","\/")
```

istead of

```
real_path.gsub("\/","\/")
```

Anyway the output is correct - You changed `/` with `\/` so You have

```
"sh -c 'sed '\''s/SHARE_PATH/\/home\/me\/www\/idata\/shared/g'\'' .... "`
```

instead of

```
`"sh -c 'sed '\''s/SHARE_PATH//home/me/www/idata/shared/g'\'' .... "`
```

and result is different from irb's result (notice the lack of doubled backslash).

For path manipulation I recommend using `File.join` ([documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/File.html#M002545))

By the way: why are You modifying the path this way? `(1)`

**Edit2:** Why are You asking about changing "/" to "/" but write the following line?

```
path = real_path.gsub("\/","\\/")
```

What are You trying to achieve? And what is Your answer to question `(1)` ?

**Edit3:**

Here We go:

```
>> real_path = "/foo/bar/dir"
=> "/foo/bar/dir"
>> path = real_path.gsub("/", "\\/")
=> "\\/foo\\/bar\\/dir"
>> puts "sed 's/SHARE_PATH/#{path}/g' #{path}/config/sphinx.yml > #{path}/config/sphinx.tmp.yml"
sed 's/SHARE_PATH/\/foo\/bar\/dir/g' \/foo\/bar\/dir/config/sphinx.yml > \/foo\/bar\/dir/config/sphinx.tmp.yml
=> nil
>>
```

but I do not understand why You need backslash in a path?

Comment: (1) I try to create "command line string" that use in "sed" command it's need directory that look like "\/foo\/bar\/dir" and full command look like -> 

run "sed 's/SHARE_PATH/\/foo\/bar\/dir/g' xxx.txt > yyy.txt"

Comment: (last) sed command need string 's/<string 1>/<string 2>/g' That why I need back slash in my directory path.